# jQuery duplicating ASP.NET button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button, duplicates

I currently have a working Web App built with ASP.NET that I'm now implementing a page slide transition for.
I have done this successfully but with one issue.

It seems jQuery is duplicating the button value when the page is rendered.

```
<input name="Submit input" data-type="button" type="submit" value="Login & Connect" />
```

So when the page is viewed, My button shows with the correctly styled "Login & Connect" with an additional "Login & Connect" also being placed inside the button.

If i remove jQuery this issue goes away but obviously page transitions no longer work.

Many thanks.

Comment: is the input button with in the transitioning div?

Comment: it's the jquery mobile full page transition with ajax loading of the next page so I assume jquery is using the body tag to transform.

Comment: Could you post the relevant jquery code and asp code.

Comment: Jquery mobile only needs to be included to do the default effect (fade) this is the asp code

<ul class="pageitem">
    <li class="button">
    <input name="Submit input" data-type="button" type="submit" value="Login & Connect"  style="height: 43px; background-position: left center; background-image: url(thumbs/user-login-icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;" /></li>
    </ul>

Comment: You can explicitly use something like : $('id or something').attr('value','');

Comment: I'm very new to JS and ASP. (Im only using ASP because someone else built it and im making changes) There is no extra code other than the code above and the includes of jquery and jquery mobile. value="Whatever" is being displayed in the button twice when jQuery is included.